# Python: how to make temporal projection from a netecdf file?

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray, geotiff

I have created an `xarray.Dataset` called `myData` that contains data for the years `1990`, `2000` and `2015`. The dataset looks like the following:

```
import xarray as xr
myData= xr.open_dataset('myData.nc')
```

[image]

I would like to have information for every year from `1990` to `2000`. I can interpolate the values from `1990` to `2015` using the following procedure:

```
import pandas as pd
def interpolate(ds, dates):
    return ds.interp(time=dates)
dates = pd.date_range('1990-01-01', '2016-01-01', freq='1Y')
myDataTime = interpolate(myData, dates)
```

Is it possible to use the trend observed from `1990` to `2015` to make projections for the years `2016`,`2017`,`2018`,`2019` and `2020`?

Comment: The tags for the question aren't particularly relevant. This is a statistical question. Many methods exists for making predictions based on time series. However, without seeing the data it's difficult to say which is more appropriate. It's possible a climatology will be the best predictor, or just a simple linear regression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any additional keyword arguments which would be passed through to the underlying interpolation engine can be provided to `ds.interp` in `kwargs`. The default interpolator is `scipy.interpolate.interp1d`, which has an argument `fill_value`:

> **fill_value:** ***array-like or (array-like, array_like) or “extrapolate”, optional***
>
> ...
>
> If “extrapolate”, then points outside the data range will be extrapolated.

So the call to interp looks like this:

```py
myData.interp(
    time=pd.date_range('1990-01-01', '2020-01-01', freq='1Y'),
    kwargs={"fill_value": "extrapolate"},
)
```

This will use the two outside points to extrapolate. If you want the linear fit over the whole time period, this will require a custom solution.

See the xarray docs on [interpolation methods](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/interpolation.html#interpolation-methods) for more information and examples.